# Design mode automatically running?

Tags: vba, event-handling, visio, mode

I'm working within Visio 2010 and I have been using my event handlers such as

```
Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal Doc As IVDocument)

'Methods being called...

End Sub
```

For some odd reason these will no longer work when the document is opened. Nor any other of my event handlers. It happened all of a sudden and I'm not quite sure why. I noticed that it seems that Design Mode seems to be highlighted upon loading every load, even when I turn it off and save the document.
So this leads me to believe that Design mode is automatically coming on when I load the document (but I have no such code) thus preventing my event handlers to stop working. But my event handlers don't work even when I turn off Design Mode.

Please help if you have any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. I used

```
Application.EventsEnabled = False
```

without ever turning it back to true after my code ran. I read to always turn it back on but it slipped through the cracks and before I knew it, I deleted the nonworking code along with the Application.EventsEnabled portion. So, if you ever turn the Events Handler off, be sure to turn it back on!

Thanks to anyone that was attempting to help me! Sorry for the vague question but I didn't have much else to go off of, I had just forgotten I turned Events to false earlier.